# Firebase Crashlytics upload missing dSYMs files for UUID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase tells me to upload missing `dSYMs` files:

[image]

I've tried doing that by getting the different files for different versions, copying them to my desktop, same with `GoogleService-Info.plist`-file and calling:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/chris/Desktop/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/chris/Desktop/dSYMs
```

My terminal said that it was successful each time but Firebase keeps telling me that files are missing. What `dSYMs` file do I have to upload then and how do I get them??? What am I missing here?

**Update:**

I found this command to find all my 'dSMSs'-files:

```
mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done
```

but the ones that I need for Firebase ("48DF4319..."  & "DE078F..") are not there. So what can I do now? Can I somehow recreate them?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working... As I said the two missing files were not on my laptop. The solution was:

**App Store Connect** -> **Test-Flight** -> **choose desired build** -> **Meta
Data** -> **Download dSYMs**

I must add that I somehow couldn't download the files by clicking *download* ... I had to *right-click* and choose *open link in new tab*. Might just be some Chrome-Bug...